# Django 400: Bad Request This field is required

Tags: python, django, json-api

I'm developing a REST API with Django and the restframework-json-api package.
I make the following request

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8000/api/students/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "data": {
        "type": "students",
        "attributes": {
            "first_name": "First Name",
            "last_name": "Last Name"
        }
    }
}'
```

And I get this response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "detail": "This field is required.",
            "status": "400",
            "source": {
                "pointer": "/data/attributes/first_name"
            },
            "code": "required"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code:
models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('first_name',)
```

views.py

```
class StudentsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser)
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'students', views.StudentsViewSet, 'student')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    )
}
```

If I instead dont use the JSONParser and use the normal django request format instead of Json API it works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: The `Content-Type` header in your request is wrong. It should be `application/vnd.api+json`. Not sure if that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a parser that is different from the recommended JSONParser referred to in the Parsers section of DRF::
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ]
}
```